# Can't navigate to linked pages with live server

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

this is my first time attempting to add a second page to the same site. I am having trouble navigating to a second page when using the live server extension in VS Code.

`<div class="testtrans"> <a href="\test.html" target="_self">TEST</a> </div>`

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOkiJ.png)

First time posting on stackoverflow, so please pardon me for the mistake I likely made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here all the files are in same directory so just filename in href attribute is enough. And one more thing, you need to use `/` not `\` if you want to access files in sub directories

```
<a href="test.html" target="_self">TEST</a>
```

```
<a href="dir/test.html" target="_self">TEST</a>
```